# Conditionally add css class in polymer

Tags: css, expression, polymer

I have an element inside a polymer component and want to add a css class conditionally.

```
<div class="bottom {{completed: item.completed}}">
```

if item.isCompleted is true, then add the .completed class.

However, I've got the following error:

Invalid expression syntax: completed?: item.completed

I don't want to put the hole subtree inside a template conditional. Is it possible to do using an expression inside an html tag? I'm using the last polymer release, is this funtionallity migrated or replaced in any way?

Comment: Can you please add the code/HTML that shows what you have tried? Here is the doc how to bind to `class` https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/expressions.html#tokenlist

Comment: I've edited the original question, the code line was missing. Now is visible

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**update Polymer 1.0**

```
<div class$="[[getClasses(item.completed)]]">
```

```
getClasses: function (completed) {
  var classes = 'bottom'
  if(completed) classes += ' completed';
  return classes;
}
```

Even when `completed` could be read from `this.item.completed` inside `getClasses()` it's important to pass it as parameter from the binding. This way Polymer re-evaluates the function `getClasses(item.completed)` each time `item.completed` changed.

**original - Polymer 0.5**

It should look like

```
<div class="bottom {{ {completed: item.completed } | tokenList }}">
```

See docs for more details: http://polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/expressions.html#tokenlist

Answer (score 18):

The tokenlist technique was valid in Polymer 0.5, but has been deprecated.

As of Polymer 1.2, the following works:

```
<dom-module ...>
  <template>
    <div class$="bottom [[conditionalClass(item.completed)]]"></div>
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer({
      ...
      conditionalClass: function(completed) {
        return completed ? 'completed' : '';
      }
    });
  <script>
</dom-module>
```

Also see similar question: [Polymer 1.0 - Binding css classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30607379/polymer-1-0-binding-css-classes)

Comment: What does the `$= ` do? I didn't see it explained anywhere. It appears I need it for this scenario, though other places where I've seen it used ` simple `=` suffices.

Comment: the `$=` is used when binding to attributes (such as: class, style, href, etc.), as opposed to properties: https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#attribute-binding

Answer (score 3):

the simplest way to do it:

```
<template>
  <style is="custom-style">
      .item-completed-true { background: red; }
  </style>
  <div class$="bottom item-completed-[[item.completed]]"></div>
</template>
```