# polymer attribute data binding with "$=" not working

Tags: polymer

I am trying to bind data to the link's href attribute instead, polymer just returns the code as is.

**Expectation**
[image: A screen acpture of hardcoded values]

**Reality**
[image]

Can someone help me understand why it's not working so that I may fix it?
thank you.

Comment: It seem to me that you are doing string interpolation. Try wrapping that whole statement inside the `href$=` into a [computed binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#annotated-computed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just made a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30607379/polymer-1-0-binding-css-classes), I think it may apply to yours as well. Apparently the string interpolation is not supported yet so you may want to try with computed properties.