# Polymer 1.0 binding properties to inline styles in template

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I would like to do something like this in polymer...

```
<dom-module id="logo-standard">
 <style>
:host {
  display: block;
}
</style>

<template>

<div class="logo-wrap">

  <div style="width: {{logoWidth}}px;">
    Some awesome logo
  </div>

</template>

<script>

(function() {

Polymer({
  is: 'logo-standard',

  properties: {

    logoWidth: {
      type: String,
      value: '400'
    }
  }

});
})();
</script>
</dom-module>
```

i.e. dynamically style an element using a property.

Is this possible? If so... how?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This question has also been answered by me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32852967/2746872)

As of [Polymer 1.2.0](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/release-notes.html#release-120httpsgithubcompolymerpolymertreev120-2015-10-22), you can now use [Compound Bindings](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#compound-bindings) to

> combine string literals and bindings in a single property binding or text content binding

like so:

```html
<img src$="https://www.example.com/profiles/{{userId}}.jpg">

<span>Name: {{lastname}}, {{firstname}}</span>
```

and your example

```html
<div style$="width: {{logoWidth}}px;">
```

***so this is no longer an issue***.

Comment: I've been using 1.2 for a while but didn't know this... very helpful thanks

Answer (score 2):

In Polymer 1.0, you will need [Computed Bindings](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#annotated-computed) to do this -

```
  <div style$="[[_computeWidth(logoWidth)]]">
    Some awesome logo
  </div>

  _computeWidth: function (width) {
      return 'width: ' + width + 'px' + ';color:red;';
  },
```

See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/t8wFADAGnGWb1pz2yLnW?p=preview) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

In Polymer 1.0 they changed something that doesn't allow you to inline styles like that. You have to use a computed styles function and have it return the values you want.

```
 <div style$="{{computeWidth}}">



 computeWidth: function () {
   return 'width:' + this.logoWidth + 'px;'
 }
```

Here is another post about this subject

[Polymer 1.0 - Binding css classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30607379/polymer-1-0-binding-css-classes)

edit: i forgot the $

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you need to create computed binding for that:

```
<dom-module id="logo-standard">
    <style>
        :host {
            display : block;
        }
    </style>
    <template>
        <div class="logo-wrap">
            <div style$="[[logoStyle(logoWidth)]]">
                Some awesome logo
            </div>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is : 'logo-standard',

            properties : {

                logoWidth : {
                    type  : String,
                    value : '400'
                }
            },
            logoStyle  : function (logoWidth) {
                return 'width: ' + logoWidth + 'px';
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

It will be possible to do without computed bindings when https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/2182 is resolved, which seems to be in progress now.

Comment: Note that `style$=` will bind value to attribute, not just element property