# Change paper-input error color dynamically

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a paper-input element which is colored red when the input is empty to mark an error has happened, but I want this same element to be orange when the user enter an invalid string to make it look like a warning.

I know I can change the color using the predefined properties like this:

```
paper-input {
  --paper-input-container-invalid-color: orange;
}
```

But this coloring is applied to any error/invalid state.

Is there a way to change this color dynamically depending on the error type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it, using updateStyles function of Polymer:

```
Polymer.updateStyles({'--paper-input-container-invalid-color': 'new_color'});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom CSS class and then apply it using for example `this.$.myInput.classList.add('error')`.

Or in this case (Polymer 1.0): [Polymer 1.0 - Binding css classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30607379/polymer-1-0-binding-css-classes)